# How to correctly encode MailTo links in ASP.NET MVC using ViewBag in BCC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First let me say that this is my first time coding in ASP.NET MVC 4 or C#. I am fresh out of school and only was taught Java. Based on other answers on stackoverflow I have the following code, but it errors out on me unless I hard code the BBC field as a string:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="@(String.Format("mailto:boss@myboss.com ?bcc={0}"
                                        ,  @ViewBag.bcc))">Send Email</a>
```

The ViewBag.bcc contains a string of email addresses (email@email.com; email2@email2.com; ...) So my question is how do I pass my ViewBag.bcc string into the code above or how can I have a user click on a link and open up Outlook and populate just the to field and the BCC field. I was trying to accomplish all of this in my controller, but I could not figure out how to get it to work correctly. I am open to anything that works, but since this is my first MVC project, this is the solution that I cam up with.

Comment: Could you provide the error you're receiving and the code where you're assigning the value to `ViewBag.bcc`? I just tried it, and with worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This anchor tag is in a view. This view is returned by an action method in a controller. In that controller, you are probably not assigning a value to Viewbag.bcc. If you are, make sure it's in the right case as it is case sensitive.

Having experienced this issue, I think this is a good moment for you to realise how harmful ViewBag is. It does not throw an exception, just dies on you silently. I recommend moving forward, you use strongly typed views. You can check the following short video on the [advantages of strongly typed views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRinkoUpEEM).